# Facing the "expected ‘;’ before ‘cout’ " error in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ (my second day) and I am a beginner at Java. So I tried to write a code to check if a number is a palindrome or not. (a number is a palindrome if the reverse of the number is the number itself, for eg: 343, 555, 6776, etc.)
So on my online compiler I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
void reverse(int);
int pow(int,int);
int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number:"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    reverse(n);
}
void reverse(int n)
{
    int up=1,u=0;
    for (int i=n;i>0;i=i/10)
    {
        int d=i%10;
        u=(pow(10,up)*d)+u
        cout << "d=" << d << "\tu=" << u << endl;
    }
    
}
int pow(int b, int e)
{
    int result=1;
    for (int i=1;i<=e;i++)
    {
        result=result*b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the above code, the function reverse reverses the number and pow is just a basic power function with the int return type. My reverse function had some problems so to check I tried to print both values of the loop (reverse was int return type but to check I declared it void and called it in the main function) by using cout and this error shows up

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘void reverse(int)’:
source_file.cpp:27:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cout’
         cout << "d=" << d << "\tu=" << u << endl;
         ^~~~
```

Pls help.....

Comment: put a ; at the end of `u=(pow(10,up)*d)+u` and everything will be fine.... hmm, thats all?

Comment: As is often the case, the error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` at the end of the `u` assignment.

This works:

`u=(pow(10,up)*d)+u;`